# Builder for Drupal 8

Tags: views, 8

Is there easy way to modify look of the frontpage/categories page etc. within Drupal 8 ?
Something like WP builders that are really easy to use and have ton of options?

I love views and things you can do with it, but always get stuck how to look them nice. Not being developer or designer point and click are my only options.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, not really. For better or for worse the Drupal community tends to lean towards custom themes and custom built components. Drupal is great for building out complex, custom content types. But it doesn't have that "premium plugin and theme" community Wordpress has that can whip you up a decent looking website in 30 minutes.

There is https://www.sooperthemes.com/drupal-modules/glazed-builder but it's not free, and I have never used it so I can't vouch for it.

There are some nice free themes by YG which may give you something like what you are looking for. https://www.drupaldevelopersstudio.com/free-drupal-themes - I installed one a while ago and was reasonably impressed.

Try searching for themes here: https://www.drupal.org/project/project_theme and sort by release date rather than "most installed". A lot of the themes you might be looking for are not necessarily going to be the most popular (see my first point).

Of course this is just my personal opinion - it's hard to give a "stackexchange" type answer, which is objectively true and provable. I encourage you to do your own research further to my response.